# Images load at different rates: uri vs require?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two images that appear on the screen at different rates despite the same markup. The only difference I can see is that one image using a uri as a source while the other uses required as it's loaded from an assets directory.

This issue appears in the simulator and on an iPhone.

[image: This is what I mean]

Code:

```js
state = { opacity: new Animated.Value(0) };
  
  componentDidMount() {
  Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
   toValue: 1,
   duration: 1000
  }).start(); 
 }
  
 render() {
  return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} >
        
        <View style={{flex: 1}} >
         <Animated.Image
          style={{ flex:1, height: undefined, width: undefined, opacity: this.state.opacity }}
          resizeMode="contain"
            source={{uri: this.props.screenProps }}
          />

        </View>

        <View>
          <Animated.Image
            source={ require('../assets/images/footer.png') }
            style={{height: 170, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, opacity: this.state.opacity}}
          />
        </View>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

I would like the calendar quote image and the footer image to load together.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when you mix external images with local images, you're going to have this problem where your local one will (hopefully) load first.

I would start off setting a state variable to handle the logic for showing your local image.

```
state = {
  opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
  isVisible: false
}
```

Create a function that will modify your recently added state variable

```
setVisibility = () => {
  this.setState({
    isVisible: true
  })
}
```

(No real need for using a function here when setting state)

Inside of your `render()` method, simply add some logic. At first this image will **not** render.

```
{this.state.isVisible &&
          <View>
            <Animated.Image
              source={require('../assets/images/footer.png')}
              style={{ height: 170, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, opacity: this.state.opacity }}
            />
          </View>}
```

Here's where the real magic happens, `Image` in React Native comes with an `onLoadEnd` event.

> Invoked when load either succeeds or fails.

You can provide additional checks for success or failure, this is not included within this example. Simply add the `onLoadEnd` prop to your external image component and pass `setVisibility` as the event handler.

```
<Animated.Image
  style={{ flex: 1, height: undefined, width: undefined, opacity: this.state.opacity }}
  resizeMode="contain"
  source={{ uri: this.props.screenProps }}
  onLoadEnd={this.setVisibility}
/>
```

You can seen an example on Expo [here](https://snack.expo.io/HyWiuQE_-).